# Performance While merging two mysql DBs

Tags: mysql, performance, merge, database-performance

I have two similar schema DBs which I need to merge. I was thinking about the performance issues which I need to keep in mind while creating the script. These are the ones which I can think of.

1. Should not Select more than a pre-specified data each time to insert in the table(use LIMITS) and the amount of data depends on the memory(RAM) we have.
2. Don't take locks on tables while selecting the data.

Can anyone please give me more points which needs to be kept in mind while creating the script?

Comment: The Locks clause can be ignored if you declare the table as INNODB

Comment: @SashiKant why, is the lock clause default in innoDB?

Comment: Read the documentation here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-transaction.html `REPEATABLE READ` will give you a consistent snapshot without locking

Comment: @Ankur: Row Level Lock is taken in a Table of type INNODb, so I thought it will be useful for you.